# Does HP Smart Tank 750 work on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

Tags: printing

I have a plan to buy [HP Smart Tank 750 All-in-One inkjet printer](https://www.hp.com/th-en/shop/hp-smart-tank-750-all-in-one-6uu47a.html?gclid=CjwKCAjwgr6TBhAGEiwA3aVuIaiT-9dwzAriAT71maT6fwyevkXBEVUNWTwV9IIdNXwLLsUi3QZJHRoCuw8QAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds). Does [HP Linux Imaging and Printing](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/downloads)  support this inkjet printer under Ubuntu 22.04 LTS ?.

Comment: We do not support hardware recommendations. If hardware does not work a bug report is needed so it can be added to Linux (not just Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

HPLIP supported devices are listed [here](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index). However, the HP Smart Tank 750 is [fully supported](https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSDriverlessPrinting) OOTB under Ubuntu 22.04 LTS  for USB and wirekess **without** HPLIP

Comment: I've not tried "driverless" printing on 22.04 but on 20.04 it had inferior quality.

Comment: I mean specifically for this printer it had inferior quality. I do photolithography for PCB etching and the difference is very vivid under the microscope. I keep meaning to raise it as a bug. Also, if both IPP-USB *and* HPLIP are present, it's struggle to get *either* of them to work *at all*.